# Using code to increment values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, window-functions

I am trying to use a simple code to increment only the values in the “chat_id” column of a table.

For the table lz_chat_archive_dup1, the column “chat_id” is has empty strings (no values). This is the partial excerpt of the table :

```
mysql> select chat_id, fullname from lz_chat_archive_dup1 LIMIT 5;
+---------+--------------+
| chat_id | fullname     |
+---------+--------------+
|         | Yw           |
|         | Shah         |
|         | Sunny Duhel  |
|         | Leong Zi Yin |
|         | Mohd Nasir   |
+---------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried to insert a value for the name “Yw” like this and it worked :

```
mysql> UPDATE lz_chat_archive_dup1 SET chat_id = '383933' where fullname = 'Yw';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

So now the table is like this :

```
mysql> select chat_id, fullname from lz_chat_archive_dup1 LIMIT 5;
+---------+--------------+
| chat_id | fullname     |
+---------+--------------+
| 383933  | Yw           |
|         | Shah         |
|         | Sunny Duhel  |
|         | Leong Zi Yin |
|         | Mohd Nasir   |
+---------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, the number of rows in this table is 2589, and for me to do it one by one is tedious and time consuming :

```
mysql> select count(*) from lz_chat_archive_dup1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2589 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I thought I could use a code something like this to update/increment only that one column, but I don’t think this is the correct syntax for MySQL. Can you please help to correct the code to customize it to work in my situation :

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 383933
UPDATE #lz_chat_archive_dup1
SET @counter = counter = @counter + 1
```

So with this code, what I am trying to achieve is increment the chat_id column so that the next value is always 1 integer higher than the previous one. So the first row is 383933, the next one should be 383934, 383935, 383936,…etc etc.

The table has > 2000 rows, so this is an excerpt of it :

```
mysql> select time, endtime, chat_id from lz_chat_archive_dup1 LIMIT 20;
+------------+------------+---------+
| time       | endtime    | chat_id |
+------------+------------+---------+
| 1594948770 | 1594948928 | 383933  |
| 1594950285 | 1594950542 |         |
| 1594950708 | 1594951085 |         |
| 1594953554 | 1594955581 |         |
| 1594955956 | 1594956551 |         |
| 1595215646 | 1595218410 |         |
| 1595215648 | 1595216044 |         |
| 1595216110 | 1595216138 |         |
| 1595220816 | 1595221144 |         |
| 1595221046 | 1595221584 |         |
| 1595221448 | 1595221505 |         |
| 1595222302 | 1595222653 |         |
| 1595236468 | 1595236848 |         |
| 1595236954 | 1595237033 |         |
| 1595293418 | 1595293589 |         |
| 1595303280 | 1595304388 |         |
| 1595303410 | 1595303822 |         |
| 1595303675 | 1595303986 |         |
| 1595304153 | 1595306613 |         |
| 1595304878 | 1595304995 |         |
+------------+------------+---------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Remembering that rows in a relational database represent unordered sets, define 'next'.

Comment: The order is by time, other than the chat_id itself.

Comment: In that case, we need to see the time column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a user variable:

```
set @rn = 383933;
update #lz_chat_archive_dup1
set chat_id = (select @rn := @rn + 1)
order by name;
```

This will assign an incrementingn number to each row, following the alphabetical order of `name`. If there are ties, it is undefined which name will get which number (a reason why you should have a primary key column in your table).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names are unique, you *could* use a `join`:

```
update lz_chat_archive_dup1 cad join
       (select cad2.*, row_number() over () as seqnum
        from lz_chat_archive_dup1 cad2
       ) cad2
       on cad2.name = cad.name
    set count = seqnum + 383933;
```

I think this might be the recommended approach in MySQL 8+.  (The statement on the deprecation of variables is a little vague on whether it would apply to `UPDATE`.)

You can also use variables.  The problem with your statement is:

```
SET @counter = counter = @counter + 1
```

This is not even setting the *column* in the table!  It is setting a variable.  Use `:=` to set parameters.  And I strongly recommend parentheses.  So, you can do:

```
DECLARE @counter int;
SET @counter = 383933;

UPDATE #lz_chat_archive_dup1
    SET counter = (@counter := @counter + 1);
```

Or, in a single statement:

```
UPDATE #lz_chat_archive_dup1 cad CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @counter := 383933) params
    SET cad.counter = (@counter := @counter + 1);
```

Comment: This seems to arbitrarily attach ids to fullnames

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Somehow, I am missing your point, because that appears to be what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with numbers starting from 1, following the alphabetic order of your `fullname` column, you can try with a helper table to run the update:

```
CREATE TABLE updtab 
AS
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fullname) AS chat_id
, fullname
FROM lz_chat_archive_dup1;
```

Then , run the update:

```
UPDATE lz_chat_archive_dup1
  SET chat_id = (
    SELECT chat_id 
    FROM updtab 
    WHERE updtab.fullname=lz_chat_archive_dup1.fullname
    )
;
```